# Dividir texto de una columna en R

Tags: r, lista, rstudio, r-dplyr

estoy practicando con la librería `dplyr` en el **dataset de TMDb** y tengo unos problemas con la columna `cast` (los actores de las películas).
Mi idea es organizar de alguna forma los actores para ver cuales son los que aparecen en mayor frecuencia, con mas peliculas, los de mejor popularidad etc.

Pongo una muestra:

```
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ budget           : int  237000000 300000000 245000000 250000000 260000000 258000000
 $ genres           : Factor w/ 1175 levels "","Action","Action, Adventure",..: 65 333 34 136 77 811
 $ original_language: Factor w/ 37 levels "af","ar","cn",..: 8 8 8 8 8 8
 $ original_title   : Factor w/ 4801 levels "#Horror","$upercapitalist",..: 414 2748 3272 3674 1970 3284
 $ popularity       : num  150.4 139.1 107.4 112.3 43.9 ...
 $ release_date     : Factor w/ 3280 levels "1916-09-04","1925-11-05",..: 2314 1944 3184 2687 2634 1939
 $ revenue          : num  2.79e+09 9.61e+08 8.81e+08 1.08e+09 2.84e+08 ...
 $ runtime          : int  162 169 148 165 132 139
 $ vote_average     : num  7.2 6.9 6.3 7.6 6.1 5.9
 $ vote_count       : int  11800 4500 4466 9106 2124 3576
 $ cast             : Factor w/ 4761 levels "","\"Weird Al\" Yankovic, Victoria Jackson, Michael Richards, David Bowe, Fran Drescher, Kevin McCarthy, Anthony G"| __truncated__,..: 3986 2299 967 802 4343 4412
 $ year             : num  2009 2007 2015 2012 2012 ...
 $ Benefits         : num  2.55e+09 6.61e+08 6.36e+08 8.35e+08 2.41e+07 ...
 $ genre            : Factor w/ 1175 levels "","Action","Action, Adventure",..: 65 333 34 136 77 811
```

la columna "cast" esta separada por "," luego de cada actor y lo que se me ocurrio fue esto:
Separar los primeros 5 Actores y forme varias columnas, A1, A2 etc y luego seleccione esas columnas como ven para ponerlas una debajo de la otra con rbind

```
actor= datos1 %>%
  select(original_title, popularity, vote_average,vote_count, cast) %>%
  separate(cast,paste("Actor",1:5),sep=',')  ## Aqui logre separar los primeros 5 actores

a1= actor%>%
  select(original_title, popularity, vote_average,vote_count, `Actor 1`)%>%
  rename(Actor= "Actor 1")

a2= actor%>%
  select(original_title, popularity, vote_average,vote_count, `Actor 2`)%>%
  rename(Actor= "Actor 2") 


a3= actor%>%
  select(original_title, popularity, vote_average,vote_count, `Actor 3`)%>%
  rename(Actor= "Actor 3")

df_actores= rbind(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5)


test2= df_actores %>%
  group_by(Actor) %>%
  filter(vote_average>mean(df_actores$vote_average))
```

No se si es la forma mas optima para hacerlo, tambien probe con `unnest` pero no se porque razón no me lo realiza.

Repito que mi idea es poder analizar los actores y el genero de la película a ver si tiene relación con los votos, popularidad y demás variables del dataset

Si existe alguna forma de poder mejorar mi código u ver otras opciones para analizarlo...

Espero me puedan ayudar, un saludo a todos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separar por columnas es posible, como lo demuestras. Pero tiene sus problemas: 1) el número de actores puede ser mayor a las columnas que permites, 2) reunir nuevamente las múltiples columnas en una sola es trabajoso.

Como bien señalas `unnest()` es una alternativa bastante directa.

Creo unos datos con una estructura similar a la tuya.

```
tibble(vote_average = c(1:2, 3), 
           cast = c("MW,ED", "AT,GC", "AT,MW,MW,QT")) -> datos
```

Se ven así:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  vote_average cast       
         <dbl> <chr>      
1            1 MW,ED      
2            2 AT,GC      
3            3 AT,MW,MW,QT
```

La clave es crear una estructura de datos en la que estén separados los nombres. En lugar de en columnas los voy a poner en una lista, usando la función `str_split`. Esa lista va a estar como columna del data.frame. Y una lista es exactamente lo que necesita `unnest` para que cada elemento se esa lista se convierta en una fila.

```
datos %>% 
  mutate(act = str_split(cast, ",")) %>% #Creo una lista de elementos separados 
  unnest(act) %>%  #Y la desanido como filas, el resto de las columnas se copiarán en cada fila
  group_by(act) %>% 
  summarise(media = mean(vote_average)) %>% 
  filter(media > mean(media))
```

Y listo.

Comment: Es lo que necesitaba! Agradezco mucho tu respuesta y tus ejemplos. Como comentario, lo único que me pasaba era que los actores que tenían un espacio luego de la coma me los tomaba doble, pero lo solucione agregando un espacio al ```str_split``` por lo que quedo todo perfecto. Un saludo!